# SSRS Switch function to fill background colour

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-grouping

I need to use the SSRS Switch function to fill background colour

```
=switch(Fields!Ref_No.Value="AAA","Green",Fields!Ref_No.Value= not like "AAA","RED"
```

How do I say if first 3 letters not like *AAA* then fill background *Red*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `Left` and `<>`:

```
=Switch(Fields!Ref_No.Value="AAA", "Green"
  , Left(Fields!Ref_No.Value, 3) <> "AAA", "Red")
```

`Left` makes sure you're considering the first three characters only as per your requirement.