# Color switch due to value of output SSRS

Tags: sql, visual-studio, reporting-services

Okay im trying to show the value of the clients report and indicate if the value is bad or good with color. But instead of showing the value in color it shows the name of the color like Green instead of 33%

```
=SWITCH(SUM(Fields!AnserValue.Value, "qWHR") <= 33, "Green", 
SUM(Fields!AnserValue.Value, "qWHR") <= 66, "Orange",
SUM(Fields!AnserValue.Value, "qWHR") >= 65, "Red")
```

Comment: your displaying the name of the color itself fro  your swtiches... i think it should be the rgb equivalent but not entirely sure... or could be the code for greem

Comment: I tried that then it just displays the code for the color

Comment: check this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19350144/ssrs-switch-function-to-fill-background-colour)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are setting the value of the text box and not the background colour property?

Your `switch` expression doesn't look like it has any problems, just make sure you are setting the appropriate property of your text box and not just the text held within it.

Comment: Any idea on how to do it otherwise?

Comment: @RenierSabrevanRooyen  I have literally just told you how to do it.  Go into the properties of your text box and put your `switch` expression into the `Background Color` property expression.

Comment: @RenierSabrevanRooyen  Here is an answer that shows you how to set the fill colour: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4993425/1350987

Comment: Sorry im very new to this xD

Comment: @RenierSabrevanRooyen  If my answer turns out to be the right one, for the benefit of other Stack Overflow users please mark it as the answer.

Comment: @RenierSabrevanRooyen  Didn't work how?  Add screenshots of what you did and the effect it had to your question.

Comment: Sorry i miss understood you this was the answer for it thank you so much